# Do sliding doors require a mezuzah?

Tags: mezuzah

I have sliding doors going out into the yard and balcony.  Do they qualify as doors that require mezuzot, or do they count as windows?

Note that this differs from this question:

[Mezuzah on deck door](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38274)

Because my question asks whether or not a mezuza is needed, and the linked question asks where to put it.

Comment: relevant: http://www.mezuzah.net/sofer.html#q82, http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=1060 - answers seem to assume you do and discuss the placement more than the need

Comment: in general, any door with two doorposts and one horizontal bar on top require mezuzot - I have found that for special cases the best is to take a picture and share it with a knowledgeable rav - the laws are quite complex especially if there is only one doorpost or two doorposts but no horizontal bar on top

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mezuzah on deck door](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38274/mezuzah-on-deck-door)

Comment: The sliding door is a door. The stationary door is a wall. So depending on which way the moving door slides and whether you put it on the right going out or coming in, the mezuzah might be affixed to the stationary 'door' because it is really a wall and the doorframe for the real door.

Comment: The requierment for mezuzos depends on the location or shape of the doorframe and not on what kind of door the frame contains.

Comment: @SamuelManuel How do you know this?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is supposing that without door, The immobile component is not Chayav Mezuza. See [here](http://www.archtoolbox.com/materials-systems/doors-windows/doorcomponentstypes.html) the components of a door. Strike Jamb and Hinge Jamb are called mezuzoth. The door itself is a priori not concerned.

1. Rambam and Raavad (In Mishne Torah Sefer Ahava Hilchoth Tefilin Umezuza, Chapter 6 Halacha 5) are controversy about the meaning of a Gemara
2. This results in that the former requires the presence of a door, the second requires simply that there are hinges.
3. You are asking following the first (but The Shulchan Aruch seems to prefer the other opinion)
4. The Kessef Mishne cit it a response from the Rambam sages of Lunel,
5. The important thing is that there opportunity to close the door (by the way I think the chute system has a hinge of status after the Halacha).

#### In conclusion,

#### According to the Rambam

The sliding type's door, with the door is Chayav Mezuza ,

#### and according to the Raavad,

it is Chayav also with the chute only, in the absense of door.